# Java JButton positioning inconsistent

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jpanel, jbutton

Basically, I have a JPanel name `canvas` with a `null` layout, and I want to add a JButton to it. What I don't understand is how the program works only half of the time. When it works the button is placed in the desired position, but randomly sometimes, it's in a completely different spot to where it should be.

(`buttons` is an ArrayList containing JButton's.)

Method that creates the JButton:

```
 public static void createButton(String dialog, int startX, int startY, int 
 sizeX, int sizeY) {

        JButton b = new JButton(dialog);
        b.setBounds(startX,startY,sizeX,sizeY);
        b.setVisible(true);
        b.setFocusable(false);
        //b.setLayout(null);
        b.addActionListener(game);


        buttons.add(b);
        canvas.add(buttons.get(buttons.size()-1));
    }
```

I run `createButton` in the main method like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    createButton("test",100,100,100,100);

    ...
}
```

I can't figure out this problem, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you set the layout of canvas to null? What container's layout is this line setting: `b.setLayout(null);`?

Comment: But having asked this, you should avoid use of null layout and use of `setBounds(...)` for component placement as this makes for very inflexible GUI's that while they might look good on one platform look terrible on most other platforms or screen resolutions and that are very difficult to update and maintain.

Comment: I set the layout of canvas to null within the JFrame constructor. I meant to remove the line  `b.setLayout(null);`, I found another post that suggested that, but it didn't work.

Comment: I read the post that mine was a duplicate. I didn't know that an absolute layout was to be avoided. If not an absolute layout, what layout would you recommend to be used to position the button at a certain x,y location?

Comment: Best to avoid absolute positioning of any kind, but rather to nest JPanels and use relative positioning, component placement that can compensate well for resizing of the GUI or running of the GUI on different platforms and screen resolutions.

Comment: In my case where width and height of the JFrame are constant and `JFrame.setResizable(false);`, is it still wrong to use absolute positioning?